# React contact form issues email js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, email, state-management

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');



const service_id = 'xxxxx'
const template_id = 'xxxxx'
const user_id = 'xxxxx'
const orderDetails = {

    name: name,
    email: email,
    phone: number,
    message: message
}




const sendEmail = () => {
    emailjs.send(service_id, template_id, orderDetails, user_id);
}

 

 <form className="contactusinfo__form" >
                        <input type="text" placeholder='Your Name' required onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                        <input type="email" placeholder='Your E-mail' required onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                        <input type="number" placeholder='Your Number' required onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)} />
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder='Your Message' id="" cols="30" rows="5" required onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} ></textarea>
                        <button style={{ fontSize: '16px', fontFamily: 'Lato' }} type='submit' onClick={sendEmail()}>
                            SEND
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

I'm trying to send an email from a contact form using emailjs and running into a bug. I had it working fine earlier but now I don't know what I've changed. My issue is that the emails come in sync with the amount of event changes in the textarea.

What's the the best practice to handle my contact form?

Comment: Hey man, find yourself a good tutorial on Formik. its what everyone uses in React and is slightly more complicated, but handles everything forms for you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the onClick props on your button and add a onSubmit props on your form to trigger the sendEmail function, or remove the form.
And if you want to handle a click on a button to send the email you should replace `onClick={sendEmail()}` by `onClick={sendEmail}`

The e.preventDefault() is necessary to prevent form submission (which reload the page in your case).